# upgrade to php 7 and keep using mssql_query functions

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, php-7

i have alot of `mssql_query` functions in my project and i want to upgrade  from php 5.5 to php 7 and keep using `mssql_query` function and `mssql_connect` , how to solve this issue without using `sqlsrv` ?

Comment: this is not possible, use mysqli_*

Comment: but i have more than 2k statements of mssql_query in sql server , i cant use mysqli_query !!!!!!!!!

Comment: then i think better no need to upgrade

Comment: Warning

This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

    mysqli_query()
    PDO::query()

Comment: thank you , but i wanna way  to use mssql_query in php 7

Comment: thank you man , but it doesnt help me !!!!!!

Comment: Please people .... READ .... `mssql` !== `mysql`

Comment: thanks mark ... any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Two libraries you may want to look at on github.

The first one: https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim acts to define the removed methods and re-direct them to `MySQLi` without you really having to change all your lines of code. But to quote directly from the repository:

> This library is meant to be a stop-gap. It will be slower than using
>   the native functions directly.
>
> You should switch to ext/pdo_mysql or ext/mysqli, and migrate to
>   prepared queries to ensure you are securely interacting with your
>   database.

It is a temporary fix that you should not rely on for the long term. You really need to migrate properly.

I've not tested this next repository but this may be useful in converting all your `mysql_*` instances to `mysqli_*` https://github.com/philip/MySQLConverterTool

As with everything, read the information provided by the developers of the packages and see if they'll handle your usecase.

Comment: i want to convert mssql and make it work in php 7 please

Comment: The question is asking about MSSQL. Nothing to do with MySQL